# Various "sizes" of 0-measured sets

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

I am looking for a formalization of an intuitive concept of size, in cases simple measure is too coarse. It will be easier for me to give an example.

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on the unit square $I^2$. Consider the following sets, all of measure 0:

- $A_1=\left\{\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)\right\}$
- $A_2=I^2\cap\left(\left\{\frac{1}{2}\right\}\times\mathbb{Q}\right)$
- $A_3=I^2\cap\left(\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\right)$
- $A_4=I^2\cap\left(\left\{\frac{1}{2}\right\}\times\mathbb{R}\right)$
- $A_5=I^2\cap\left(\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{R}\right)$

If $\sigma$ is some formalization of my intuition of size in these cases, I would expect $$\sigma(A_1)<\sigma(A_2)<\sigma(A_3)<\sigma(A_4)<\sigma(A_5).$$

I know that $A_1,A_2,A_3$ may be distinguished from $A_4,A_5$ according to their cardinality, but that's again too coarse.

Another issue is this: what sort of functions will be $\sigma$-preserving? Of course, bijections will not suffice, as they may take $A_4$ into $I^2$, which is naturally "larger".

I believe there should be some term or theory which investigates finer "sizes". Do you know of such?

Comment: An interesting question.  You may need to look at various measures which work for different purposes.  It is not obvious to me that you want $\sigma (A_3) \lt \sigma (A_4)$.  Certainly $A_3$ is countable and $A_4$ is not, but $A_3$ is dense in the square and $A_4$ is not.  Fractal dimension of closure is one measure you could use, which gives $\sigma(A_1)<\sigma(A_2)=\sigma(A_4)<\sigma(A_3)=\sigma(A_5)$.  I'm not saying your intuition is wrong, just pointing out one idea and its consequence.

Comment: Yes, I was also not "sure" about $\sigma(A_3)<\sigma(A_4)$... thanks for the [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension)!

Answer (score 1):

I collected together a number of different concepts here a few years back:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:CRGreathouse/Large_and_small_sets

They mostly focus on the discrete, though.

Comment: That's a nice list, I'll have a look, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the concept of Hausdorff dimension! Interesting!